# Licensing server will only respond with ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED

Tags: android, google-play

Variant of this question have been asked before. But from the current Google documentation it seems things have changed and many answers are obsolete.

I'm completing an App that will be sold on the Google Play Store. The last thing to implement and test is license verification using LVL. The licensing server will only respond with ERROR_NOT_MARKET_MANAGED.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html says "Using the Google Play Developer Console, you can debug and test an application's licensing implementation, prior to publishing the application". Then Table 1 on this webpage clearly states a publisher account "Can check license before upload".

I interpret this to mean that, when logged in to my test device using my publisher account I should be able to get a licensing server response for my App without uploading an APK.

Am I mistaken? I ask because other related stackoverflow questions state an APK must be uploaded. That was the case in the past but doesn't appear to be true now if I am interpreting the documentation correctly.

Comment: Yes you should be able to test it prior going live. The test device you mention is it simulator or actual device? Is valid test account setup correctly in test device? Make sure latest Google APIs Add-on is installed on simulator or Google Play client is installed on actual device. Clearing Cache from Google Play store helps sometimes

Comment: I'm trying to test this without uploading an APK to the Play Store. I'm testing on a real device with the latest Google Play client and definitely using a correct account on the phone (publisher account). And I cleared the Google Play cache and data as recommended in other posts. It still doesn't work. I've worked around the problem by uploading an alpha version of the APK to the store. I'll explain more details of my workaround in an answer later if no-one else answers as to how to test without uploading an APK.